# Further Mistakes at the Ministry of Magic

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

In page 203 of *Goblet of Fire*, a newspaper article states that the Ministry has made further mistakes, that Mad-Eye made a false alarm and that Arthur Weasley involved the Ministry in an embarrassing scene. I don't understand any of these claims.

> FURTHER MISTAKES AT THE MINISTRY OF MAGIC
>   It seems as though the Ministry of Magics troubles are not yet at an end, writes Rita Skeeter, Special Correspondent.
>   Recently under fire for its poor crowd control at the Quidditch World Cup, and still unable to account for the disappearance of one of its witches, the Ministry was plunged into fresh embarrassment yesterday by the antics of Arnold Weasley, of the Misuse of Muggle Artefacts Office.

Answer (score 8):

The full quote from the *Daily Prophet* article is as follows:

> Arnold Weasely, who was charged with possession of a flying car two years ago, was yesterday involved in tussle with several Muggle law-keepers ("policemen") over a number of highly aggressive dustbins.  Mr. Weasley appears to have rushed to the aid of "Mad-Eye" Moody, the aged ex-Auror who retired from the Ministry when no longer able to tell the difference between a handshake and an attempted murder.  Unsurprisingly, Mr. Weasely found, upon arrival at the Mr. Moody's heavily guarded house, that Mr. Moody had once again raised a false alarm.  Mr. Weasely was forced to modify several memories before he could escape from the policemen, but refused to answer *Daily Prophet* questions about why he had involved the Ministry in such an undignified and potentially embarrassing scene.

To understand this article, we first need to go back earlier in the book, when Arthur (the *Daily Prophet* got his name wrong to boot) was called to help Moody:

> Amos Diggory’s head was sitting in the middle of the flames like a  large,  bearded egg.  It  was  talking  very  fast,  completely  unperturbed by the sparks flying around it and the flames licking its ears. “...Muggle  neighbors  heard  bangs  and  shouting,  so  they  went  and   called   those   what-d’you-call-’ems — please-men.   Arthur, you’ve got to get over there —”
>
> “Here!” said Mrs. Weasley breathlessly, pushing a piece of parchment,  a  bottle  of  ink,  and  a  crumpled  quill  into  Mr.  Weasley’s hands.
>
> “— it’s a real stroke of luck I heard about it,” said Mr. Diggory’s head. “I had to come into the office early to send a couple of owls, and I found the Improper Use of Magic lot all setting off — if Rita Skeeter gets hold of this one, Arthur —”
>
> “What  does  Mad-Eye  say  happened?”  asked  Mr.  Weasley,  unscrewing  the  ink  bottle,  loading  up  his  quill,  and  preparing  to  take  notes.
>
> Mr. Diggory’s head rolled its eyes. “Says he heard an intruder in his yard. Says he was creeping toward the house, but was ambushed by his dustbins.”
>
> “What  did  the  dustbins  do?”  asked  Mr.  Weasley,  scribbling  frantically.
>
> “Made one hell of a noise and fired rubbish everywhere, as far as I  can  tell,”  said  Mr.  Diggory.  “Apparently  one  of  them  was  still rocketing around when the please-men turned up —”
>
> Mr. Weasley groaned. “And what about the intruder?”
>
> “Arthur,  you  know  Mad-Eye,”  said  Mr.  Diggory’s  head,  rolling  its  eyes  again.  “Someone  creeping into  his  yard  in  the  dead  of  night?  More  likely  there’s  a  very  shell-shocked  cat  wandering  around somewhere, covered in potato peelings. But if the Improper Use of Magic lot get their hands on Mad-Eye, he’s had it — think of his record — we’ve got to get him off on a minor charge, something in your department — what are exploding dustbins worth?”
>
> “Might be a caution,” said Mr. Weasley, still writing very fast, his brow  furrowed.  “Mad-Eye  didn’t  use  his  wand?  He  didn’t  actually  attack anyone?”
>
> “I’ll  bet  he  leapt  out  of  bed  and  started  jinxing  everything he
>   could  reach  through  the  window,” said  Mr.  Diggory,  “but  they’ll have a job proving it, there aren’t any casualties.”
>
> “All  right,  I’m  off,”  Mr.  Weasley  said,  and  he  stuffed  the parchment  with  his  notes  on  it  into his  pocket  and  dashed  out  of  the kitchen again

This incident is how Mr. Weasely got involved.  There was some sort of commotion at Mad-Eye Moody'd residence, causing Muggle neighbors to call the police.  Arthur was called in to try to help Moody avoid a larger sentence (apparently the first Ministry representative on the scene has jurisdiction and can decide all charges, in the Wizard world?).  The "false claim" was that of Moody claiming he had been attacked, when in fact there was no intruder at all.

Of course, later in the book we learn that

> The commotion was actually Barty Crouch Jr. attacking and kidnapping the real Mad-Eye Moody.  The story about the dustbins was something Crouch Jr. made up, a story he felt the wizarding world would believe the real Moody might actually say, in order to explain away the commotion that Moody's muggle neighbors heard in the first place.